# ActionbarSherlock Sliding Menu with Tabs scroll issue

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I am using Sliding Menu and ActionBarSherlock in my application. Since I need to support old APIs so I cannot use the normal action bar.

I have multiple tabs (4-5) on the home page and also the sliding menu library works good. The issue I am facing is related to 2.3+ Android , when I click on any tab of home page and try to slide the tabs it works first time, but once you have scrolled to reach to last tab or any other tab then it is not easy to scroll back to the first tab. Instead the library slides the page and does not slide the tab.

One my Nexus 4 it works without any issues and is very smooth but when I use it on my device with 2.3.5 it is erratic.

Any pointers to this issue would be of great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this a few times also. The best solution I have seen/used is to change the touch mode of the sliding menu based on the tab being displayed i.e.

```
getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
```

or

```
getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
```

when you're away from the first tab. I suggest using `TOUCHMODE_MARGIN` so that the menu can still be opened. Then, when the first tab is reached you can switch the touch mode back to `TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN`. An Alternative is to keep the touch mode always as `TOUCHMODE_MARGIN`.

I hope this is of some help.

Comment: Tried one more variation as suggested in some other places : `setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);` . But then it disturbs everything, the first tab is shown blank when app is loaded, when sliding happens the tab contents and back page contents  (the page behind) overlap.

Comment: That is strange, I have never experienced any of these functions affecting layouts. Just to clarify, you have tried the methods i suggested and the one you mention?